# How to deal with many to many relationships with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

OK so I have two entities in my data model (let's say entityA and entityB), both of these entities have a to-many relationship to each other.

I have setup a NSFetchedResultsController to fetch a bunch of entityA. Now I'm trying to have the section names for the tableview be the title of entityB.

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"entityB.title"
```

Now this causes a problem, where by the section name returned from that relationship appears to be ({title1}) or ({title1,title2...titleN}) obviously depending on how many different entityB's are involved. This doesn't look great in a tableview and doesn't group the objects as I would like.

What I would like is a section per entityB title with entityA appearing under each section, under multiple sections if necessary. I'm at a loss as how I am supposed to achieve this whether I need to update the predicate to get the entity to appear multiple times or whether I need to update the section and header functions to do some processing as the controller loops through the objects.

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get that because the call @"entityB.title" is going to return an array|set of titles.  That is what you are seeing as it is translating into:

```
NSSet *titles = [myEntityA valueForKeyPath@"entityB.title"];
```

To fix this, you need to reverse your NSFetchedResultsController so that you are fetching EntityA objects *through* EntityB objects.  Then your sectionKeyPath (and your primary sort) would be against just @"title".

Comment: I don't know how you get NSFetchedResultsController to fetch EntityA objects through EntityB objects, but I just fetched EntityB objects and used the UITableViewDataSource methods to get EntityA from what the NSFetchedResultsController gave me. It ended up not being not as bad as I originally thought it would be.

Comment: Trying to do this myself. Phil or Marcus, can you expound a little bit more on how to do this? Looking all over in stackoverflow and google, not having much luck. WOuld appreciate any help.

Comment: @JPK: open a new question describing your exact problem and then I can expound upon it.

Comment: I'm not convinced this answer is correct. The question states "many to many"... I'm pretty sure this advice would only work of there was a one-to-many relationship at work here, so that when accessing your EntityA through each EntityB there would only be one EntityA returned... Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @DuncanBabbage you could build a test can and confirm/disprove it yourself :)

Comment: I don't need to build a test... I am trying to implement it with existing code that works fine but currently doesn't use an NSFetchedResultsController and would benefit from it for performance... I have been actively trying to implement what you suggest but to date, I haven't been able to get this approach to work. Would be pleased for any additional pointers if you have them. And am working towards my own question (as you suggested above to someone else) if existing ones don't resolve my issues. :)

Comment: Having just noticed what you are author of, I am going to presume that what you've said is correct. Obviously therefore all this head-banging I'm going against this wall may eventually lead to this working, which is great... but there is something not obvious in the Kung Fu here that I'm obviously not getting. I can get my view to work the way I want with a fetch request that doesn't use an NSFetchedResultsController, and I can display a view using an NSFetchedResultsController, but getting my many-to-many relationship to work as a valueForKeyPath is eluding me. Gah! :)

Comment: @DuncanBabbage If you do end up creating your own question, please email me the link to it (marcus at cimgf dot com) so that I make sure I take a look at it.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra inspired by increased confidence that this *could* work, I've managed to get it to work. Now just refactoring other parts of the to do things the NSFetchedResultsController way so I can see if this really did help performance. :)